# How to hide ?id= into net side

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, url-rewriting, web-config, url-routing

I have website which build in .net (MVC). We provide dynamic website using get id concept on web configure. We fetch the user id from the name which is saw after clue24.com/ .

We give universal id for user like clue24.com/innoventaa, After getting the class name, our we configure convert this into http://clue24.com/UserClass/Default.aspx?id=1007 . I would like saw only http://clue24.com/UserClass/Default.aspx not id . How can i do this?

Please let me know your expert view.

Thanks and Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the ID elsewhere, for instance in `Session`. When you navigate to the page, you won't check the query string, but the session object.

Other option is to store the id directly in the aspx file - in a hidden field or in ViewState (cause you use webforms).

Comment: HI, 

Thanks for your response, But we are giving website for our clients by this,

If i use session for id storage. Its conflict when more than two class website open in same browser. That's why we drop the idea of session storage. 

Our system fetch the data on server side via this id. 

have you any other idea?

Waiting for your expert advice!